# Property 'type' does not exist on button

Tags: reactjs, typescript, definitelytyped

I have this button component:

```
export interface ButtonProps extends React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement> {
    small?: boolean;
}

class Button extends React.Component<ButtonProps> { ... }
```

But when I try to do:

```
<Button type="submit"></Button>
```

I get this error:

> Property 'type' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes & Readonly & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>'

Why? Isn't the `type` attribute part of `React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>`? What is the proper/recommended way to set this attribute?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
export interface ButtonProps
  extends React.DetailedHTMLProps<
    React.ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>,
    HTMLButtonElement
  > {
  small?: boolean
}

class ButtonZ extends React.Component<ButtonProps> {
  render() {
    return <></>
  }
}
```

If you're using VSCode as your IDE hovering over an HTML component and inspecting the tooltip is  a good way to see the types and props.

Comment: Thanks :) Is it really necessary to have the interface extend  `React.DetailedHTMLProps`, or will `React.ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>` suffice?